# Les connotations de « Tu as la malchance. »

Tags: sens

J’ai une question à propos de la phrase

> « Tu as la malchance. »

Son sens est assez clair, mais je me demande si elle exprime le fait que celui qui la dit dédaigne celui qui écoute.

Mieux dit, est-ce qu’elle sous-entend quelque chose comme

> « C’est dommage que tu aies la déveine. J’espère que tu iras mieux plus
>   tard. »

Ou pensez-vous qu’elle se rapproche plutôt de

> « Maintenant tu a la malchance comme tu le mérites. Comme on fait son
>   lit on se couche. »

Bien entendu, l’utilisation de la voix influe sur le sens apparent de la phrase. Hormis l’intonation, peut-on dire quelque chose sur les sentiments qu’elle éveille? Et est-ce qu’il y a des façons subtiles de lui donner l’air méprisant ou compatissant?

Comment: @Mina, Merci pour avoir amélioré ma question. Pouvez-vous dire pourquoi « se rapprocher de » est un meilleur choix que « approcher » ici ?

Comment: D'abord, en relisant ce que j'ai ecrit, je trouve que j'aurai dû ecrire _Ou pensez-vous que le sens se rapproche plutôt de_ pas _la question_.

Comment: Ensuite, entre [rapprocher](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rapprocher/66526), [se rapprocher](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/se_rapprocher/66528?q=rapprocher#65780), [s'approcher et approcher](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/approcher/4772),  seul _approcher_ ne dénote pas d'un rapprochement analogique.

Comment: J'ai choisi _se rapprocher_ pour exprimer: Présenter des rapports, des similitudes avec - _Une école de peinture qui se rapproche du cubisme_ est l'example donné par Larousse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'expression ne s'emploie pas seule, on dit plutôt :

- Tu as la malchance *avec toi*  (ou plus rarement car plus menacante *sur toi*)
- Tu as *de* la malchance (en ce moment)
- Tu es malchanceux.

En fait la malchance est rarement usité de nos jours :

- Tu as le mauvais œil (sur toi)
- Tu n'as pas de chance
- Ce n'est pas ton jour (ou ta semaine)

L'expression en elle-même est équivoque, seul le contexte (dont la voix peut faire partie), mais surtout la phrase qui suit (ou qui peut précéder) marquera de l'ironie, de l'humour, de la férocité, du sadisme, ou au contraire de l'empathie,  de la commisération,  de l'attendrissement.

La phrase 'qui suit' peut être tout aussi indécise à l'écrit :

> Tu n'a pas de chance, comme je te plains !

peut être dite avec ironie ou commisération...  ce qui peut être un cauchemar ou un espace de liberté pour un metteur en scène.